# Is there any issue here using select statement in nvl function?

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I have this below simple query:

```
 Select * from Table_A 
    where approved_date > NVL((Select Max(Last_Processed_Time) from Table_B),
TO_DATE('2021/04/19 11:13:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

If I run the query, it doesn't return any rows, but, it return records when I run the query as below:

```
Select * from Table_A 
where approved_date > TO_DATE('2021/04/19 11:13:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

I have to check Table_B record count, In my case, Table_B is empty. I am checking if Table_B is empty, and if it is empty, I will use a hardcoded date. so I am using NVL. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Maybe because `max(Last_Processed_Time)` is not less than any `approved_date`?

Comment: @astentx, Table_B is empty, I have to check if Table_B is empty, If empty I will compare with a hardcode date

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with an empty table [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=862d022f8566b738169e1b98b887acc5). Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with DDL & DML statements that replicates your problem as your query should work with an empty table.

Answer (score 2):

I have created table_b and table_a

```
CREATE table table_b(
  Last_Processed_Time date
);

CREATE table table_a(
  approved_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO table_a SELECT hire_date FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

```
[2021-04-21 14:46:02] 107 rows affected in 54ms
```

And your query is working fine

```
Select * from table_a 
where approved_date > NVL((Select Max(Last_Processed_Time) from Table_B), TO_DATE('1999/04/19 11:13:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

And I got the rows.

```
APPROVED_DATE
-------------------
1999-12-07 00:00:00
1999-08-10 00:00:00
1999-11-16 00:00:00
2000-03-08 00:00:00
1999-12-12 00:00:00
2000-02-06 00:00:00
1999-10-15 00:00:00
2000-01-29 00:00:00
1999-11-23 00:00:00
2000-01-24 00:00:00
2000-02-23 00:00:00
2000-03-24 00:00:00
2000-04-21 00:00:00
2000-04-21 00:00:00
1999-05-24 00:00:00
2000-01-04 00:00:00
1999-06-21 00:00:00
2000-02-03 00:00:00
1999-12-19 00:00:00
1999-06-21 00:00:00
2000-01-13 00:00:00
```

```
[2021-04-21 14:46:23] 21 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 106ms (execution: 44ms, fetching: 62ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing anything here?

If `(Select Max(Last_Processed_Time) from Table_B)` is greater than the largest `approved_date` in `table_a` then you will filter out all the rows and the result set will be empty.

> but, it return records when I run the query as below:
>
> ```
> Select *
> from   Table_A 
> where  approved_date > TO_DATE('2021/04/19 11:13:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
> ```

Then you probably have rows where the `approved_date` is greater than 2021-04-19T11:13:44 but is not greater than the maximum `last_processed_time` in `table_b`.

Comment: No, in my case Table_B is empty

Comment: @BlackCat so provide some sample data. [It is not reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=139570f06cb204c7e0492af24462f389)

Comment: @BlackCat Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67191915/edit) your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for (minimal examples of) your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for sample data that replicates the problem. You have not included the detail that `table_b` is empty in the question and that is very important information so please help us to help you by giving us a complete setup so we can reproduce the issue.